# what exactly is a static web server?

Tags: web, gruntjs

Currently I have been experimenting with using **grunt** and am going to use **grunt-contrib-qunit** and it seems like it requires **grunt-contrib-connect**.

What I am really confused about is that grunt-contrib-connect starts a **static**  web server.
The word **static** is what really baffles me. Do I need a web server for my *static* files such as images, html, css, js, etc. during development?

I am currently studying PHP and am using **xampp** which includes **apache**. How does it differ from web servers like Apache? Would I be able to use them side by side since I think they will be using different *ports*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect is a server written in JavaScript & Node. There's a [nice introduction over here](http://howtonode.org/connect-it) to it, plus [this simple tutorial](http://opensource.about.com/od/tutorials/a/Write-Your-Own-Open-Source-Web-Server-With-Node-Js.htm). The advantage of using it over say a local apache/nginx setup is that there is a lot less to configure; a lot of Node projects are written entirely in HTML/CSS/JavaScript and so they don't need the extras (PHP, MySQL and the like). This means you can be up and running in minutes, you can create as many servers as you'd like, for running applications that need to be on a server.

Indeed, the [grunt-contrib-connect documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) gives you an example of running multiple servers on different ports:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    site1: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        base: 'www-roots/site1'
      }
    },
    site2: {
      options: {
        port: 9001,
        base: 'www-roots/site2'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You will be able to run the connect server with your local xampp install providing that you don't override the port that your apache installation is running on (I believe port 80 is the default, so any other and it'll be OK).

Comment: i have a question with having 2 simulatenously running servers.

let's say i run localhost:80/MyProject/index.php

then i also run grunt connect on port 4000 with livereload. How would livereload be triggered while i'm on localhost:80?

Comment: What you want is the livereload extension that you can toggle on/off in your browser: http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions- - Personally I've not worked simultaneously on two livereload instances so I don't know if this works or not, so give it a try and see what happens. :)

Answer (score 7):

**A static web server exactly** is a web server which serves only *static content*: any files (incl. html, js, css) that are available at the moment they are requested by the client.

A static web server is not meant to serve *dynamically generated content* which does not exist but needs to be constructed **on-the-fly** (e.g. after extracting certain info from a database, using server-side language such as PHP etc).